# Enable Basic Authentication for Azure App Service WebApi OWIN

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, iis-8, basic-authentication

I have an ASP.Net 4.5.2 MVC5 WebApi 5.2.3 Application that uses OAuth/Jwt security in general via the OWIN Pipeline. Now, I have an external service web-hook that calls one of my WebApi Controllers via POST. This webhook service only supports Basic Authentication over Https. This is fine, if I could only get my Filter (or whatever) to work.

I based my filter on a nice [example by Rick Strahl](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter) However, when I add this class and then my [MyBasicAuthFilter] above my ApiController  Action, all I get is a server error 500 message with {"Message":"An error has occurred."}.

When I remove the "Authorization: Basic dXNlcasdfasfdsfasd=" header from the POST call, then the code enters my new Filter fine. Oh great :-[. So something earlier in the pipleline does not like the fact that this header exists. I suspected IIS settings after reading up a bit. But after trying to coerce the Azure App Service IIS via my Web.Config, and promptly blocking all access to my site, I thought I'd come here for some tips.

Ideas/Tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is the scoop on what was going on here. The existing JsonWebTokenValidationHandler (Message Handler) was only looking for a "Bearer" token in the header. If any other token appeared, then it would label it as a potential attack an return HttpStatus 500. If no token at all was in the header, then it would return the challenge HttpStatus 401. Anyway, the best solution for my minimalistic BasicAuth requirement (on top of JWT tokens) is the following (complete) content of my JsonWebTokenValidationHandler.cs. This now handles both Bearer (JWT) tokens and Basic Auth tokens. Comments welcome.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

public class JsonWebTokenValidationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public string SymmetricKey { get; set; } // A0 client secret

    public string Audience { get; set; } // A0 client ID

    public string Issuer { get; set; } // A0 our A0 domain

    private static bool TryRetrieveToken(HttpRequestMessage request, out string token)
    {
        token = null;
        IEnumerable<string> authzHeaders;

        if (!request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out authzHeaders) || authzHeaders.Count() > 1)
        {
            // Fail if no Authorization header or more than one Authorization headers  
            // are found in the HTTP request  
            return false;
        }

        // Remove the bearer token scheme prefix and return the rest as ACS token  
        var bearerToken = authzHeaders.ElementAt(0);
        token = bearerToken.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? bearerToken.Substring(7) : bearerToken;

        return true;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string token;
        HttpResponseMessage errorResponse = null;

        if (TryRetrieveToken(request, out token))
        {
            try
            {
                // ++
                // Added BasicAuth to our JWT Auth
                // If it is a BasicAuth token, then check it first and bypass JWT validation
                // See Asp.Net WebApi security book for infos on this.
                //
                if (token.Contains("Basic"))
                {
                    var authHeader = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(token.Substring(6)));

                    // find first : as password allows for :
                    int idx = authHeader.IndexOf(':');
                    if (idx < 0)
                        return null;

                    string username = authHeader.Substring(0, idx);
                    string password = authHeader.Substring(idx + 1);

                    // Check the user's validity and reuse the JWT challenge 401 exception if not valid.
                    if (!ValidateBasicAuthUser(username, password))
                    {
                        throw new JsonWebToken.TokenValidationException(
                            $"Username or password missmatch for username: {username}");
                    }

                    // If OK, then let them in and continue
                    var identity = new BasicAuthenticationIdentity(username, password);
                    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // --

                    // Handle JWT Tokens here or return server error 500 if it is not a valid token.
                    var secret = this.SymmetricKey.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');

                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = JsonWebToken.ValidateToken(
                        token,
                        secret,
                        audience: this.Audience,
                        checkExpiration: true,
                        issuer: this.Issuer);

                    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (JWT.SignatureVerificationException ex)
            {
                errorResponse = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, ex);
            }
            catch (JsonWebToken.TokenValidationException ex)
            {
                errorResponse = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorResponse = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
            }
        }

        return errorResponse != null ?
            Task.FromResult(errorResponse) :
            base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// rht: Check our BasicAuth passwords e.g. from Cb WebHook
    /// Usage: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool ValidateBasicAuthUser(string username, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            return false;

        var ok = false;
        //
        // Our valid usernames and passwords
        //
        switch (username)
        {
            case "your user 1 here":
                {
                    if (password == "your password here") ok = true;
                }
                break;
            case "your user 2 here or from DB, whatever":
                {
                    if (password == "pwd") ok = true;
                }
                break;
        }

        return ok;
    }
} // cl

//
// See: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter
// And Asp.Net WebApi Security book.
public class BasicAuthenticationIdentity : GenericIdentity
{
    public BasicAuthenticationIdentity(string name, string password)
        : base(name, "Basic")
    {
        this.Password = password;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Basic Auth Password for custom authentication
    /// </summary>
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```